# Dynamically modify TypeScript classes through a generic function

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, factory

How do you create a static method on a class through a generic function?

Let's say you want to add a function `make` on a set of classes, depending on whether the class has a static `shouldMake` being true or false. These `make` functions should then be factories, creating instances of the classes.

The following JavaScript works:

```
function makeMaker( cls )
{
    if ( cls.shouldMake )
        cls.make = function( ...args ) { return new cls( ...args ); };
    return cls;
}
```

You can run a set of classes through this:

```
outClasses = inClasses.map( makeMaker );
```

I'd expect something like this to work in TypeScript:

```
function makeMaker< T >( cls: T ): T
{
    if ( cls.shouldMake )
        cls.make = function( ...args: any[] ) { return new cls( ...args ); }
    return cls;
}
```

However, this causes a few errors:

> Property 'shouldMake' does not exist on type 'T'.

and

> Property 'make' does not exist on type 'T'.

and

> Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

In this case, `cls` would infer a *value of type T*. I'd expect T if you provide a class as the argument (`cls`) to be some kind of "type of the class", e.g. the constructor. Changing it to a constructor:

```
function makeMaker< T >( cls: { new( ...args: any[] ): T } )
{
    if ( cls.shouldMake )
        cls.make = function( ...args: any[] ) { return new cls( ...args ); };
    return cls;
}
```

causes:

> Property 'shouldMake' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.

and

> Property 'make' does not exist on type 'new (...args: any[]) => T'.

This makes kind of sense, although this error occurs even if `makeMaker` is never called. So, we'll need to ensure the constructor of T (the T class itself) to be a type where `shouldMake` and `make` properties is valid.

How would you do that? Basically, how do you let a class **type** inherit from an interface where we can constrain this, or, how do you describe valid *static* properties on a class? This seems not to be supported according to: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13462 and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600 so would a large JavaScript code base depending on this logic be impossible to convert to TypeScript (i.e. excluding a more or less complete rewrite)?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a use case for *maybe methods* and type casting. Before I get to the actual solution, I will cover the necessary preambles. First, we can declare an interface that is implemented for all class types that can become makers (with a constructor of objects of type `T`):

```
interface Class<T> {
    shouldMake: boolean;
    new(... args: any[]): T;
}
```

Then we define an interface for all object that can be makers (they make objects of type `T`). Whether the method is available will depend on the field `shouldMake`.

```
interface Maker<T> {
    shouldMake: boolean;
    make?(...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Now we can implement `makeMaker`. If we cast our class object to `C & Maker<T>`, then `make` can exist and we can set it normally. The important part of the method's prototype is to make sure that `C` has a constructor and the `shouldMake` field, and that the return type retains all information about `C`, plus the extra method in `Maker`.

```
function makeMaker<T, C extends Class<T>>( cls: C ): C & Maker<T>
{
    if (cls.shouldMake)
        (<C & Maker<T>>cls).make = function( ...args: any[] ) { return new cls( ...args ); };
    return cls;
}
```

The resulting JavaScript is equivalent to what you had in the beginning:

```
function makeMaker(cls) {
    if (cls.shouldMake)
        cls.make = function (...args) { return new cls(...args); };
    return cls;
}
```

---

Here's an example of usage. Note that you should always check whether `make` is available, as the compiler cannot verify that for you.

```
class Foo {
    private name?: string;

    static shouldMake = true;

    new(name?: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    hasName(): boolean {
        return typeof this.name === 'string' && this.name !== '';
    } 
}

const FooMaker = makeMaker<Foo, typeof Foo>(Foo);
if (FooMaker.shouldMake) {
    let unnamedFoo = FooMaker.make();
    console.log(unnamedFoo.hasName()); // false
} else {
    // unreachable in this case
}
```